# A way to download source of each nuget package?

Tags: git, github, nuget, open-source

I'm working in a strong regulation context, in which using opensource libraries (which is almost synonym of *on GitHub* nowadays) is permitted as long as you're able to have the source of all these libs.

During feasibility stage , I've been linking libs on my project using nuget, storing the project in Git, so far so good.

Before going in production stage, I would like to be able (at least for each production release, even for nightly builds if possible) to have "somewhere" the source of all the libraries that I use.

There might be a strategy for doing this without nuget but with git and submodules, but It doesn't look obvious for me. 
Anyone has an idea about how to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just my opinion but automating source retrieval just for the sake of complying is somewhat silly. What's the value in having the code but in 99% never look at it? Compliance should be checked *before* using in your project. What if you find out a component is offending any of your policies when going to production stage?

Comment: That's just the silly scenarios you go into when playing with regulatory aspect : you have an important bug to fix quickly because lifes depend on it ;   what if the github project is shut down by its owner ? at your trial, you say "they're dead because the github owner shut down his project" ?

Comment: This said, I agree with you on the principe, but people just get crazy with regulations ; example of what you find in IEC 62304-amd1 2015 : _If the HAZARD could arise from a failure of the SOFTWARE SYSTEM to behave as specified, the probability of such failure shall be assumed to be 100 percent._  : real life analogy : If being hit by the lightning is possible for you, then consider that you have 100% chances it will happen ...

Comment: I just wanted to suggest that manually downloading the sources of the components you intend to use, making it part of the process of deciding for a specific solution would be what this regulation tries you achieve. I know there's never enough time to do it "the right way" ...

Comment: You could check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517422/2303202

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible to do automatically. I would even say that is it not always easy to manually find proper revision in the github.

> which is almost synonym of on GitHub nowadays

It is almost. For example, System.Data.SQLite uses even another VCS: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/brlist. You can notice that it's not easy to spot a version there.

If you need to strictly follow the regulation you probably should be rebuilding the dependencies yourself, from known sources.

Comment: Your SQLite example is relevant .. I think that all the libraries I used till now are on github, but it might not be the case in the future...

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the project site will lead you to the GitHub page. There you will be able to download the source of the nuget package.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NGitHub/0.7.0-beta2